# TinyMCE text conversion issue

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using the TinyMCE 5.8.1 editor against existing data, where the textarea has MIME content:

"MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Dear Steven San,┬á

etc etc"

As soon as I call tinyMCE.init the format gets changed, and saving the data the textarea now shows different MIME content:

"MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Dear Steven San,┬á etc etc"

All of the HTML formatting seems to be stripped, and the Content-Type changes from text/html to text/plain.

I'm struggling to find anything about this in the TinyMCE documentation, or via google.

How do I stop, or control this apparent stripping of html formatting?

p.s. for new documents, everything is working fine, and storing as text/plain.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are setting the content of the textarea that you are initializing TinyMCE on? Specifically where does the mime type come into it? Are you using a meta tag?

Comment: I am using TinyMCE with HCL Domino, to create and edit records in a database.  Creating/Editing new Rich Text is stored as "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8".  To be clear, creation/editing of new records is fine, no issues at all.  My problem is when editing old data, where the old data's Rich Text is stored as "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".   As soon as the editor is initialized all of the formatting of the RichText is lost so it's just one big string of text.